# How to place messages in the image/block like the built in messaging app in android?

Tags: android, messaging

I have made a messaging android app and we get messages in simple string.But I want to place the messages as show in the image. Whoever sends the messages should get that message in blue box and whatever I type should get the message in green box. In short I want to make like the android built in messaging application.

We should also be able to send the images and videos in that android application. 
My application which I made can send only the messages.

Please help me. In short that android app will be exactly like "Whatsapp", "WeChat" etc.
I would appreciate for your help.

Comment: Did you write at least a line of code? And if you have, can you post the code

Answer (score 0):

This is really a big issue.. But this one can help you start.

It is an open source application for android with instant messages

https://code.google.com/p/simple-android-instant-messaging-application/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk

Hope that will make sense